# does it matter for a new line in the multipart/form data

Tags: http

is it same for

```
Connection: Keep-Alive

-----------------------8cd57c336084737
```

and

```
Connection: Keep-Alive


-----------------------8cd57c336084737
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second one your part has a line break as its contents. Whether that makes a difference or not depends on how your request is processed further.